# Excel VBA - Copy Rows by Unique Value in Column A

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, macros

I have managed so far to pull all my data from different sources into a “Master List”.  From here I would like to pull all rows with matching values from column A into its own sheet.

I.E. All rows that start with `SF-1` will be copied into its own sheet and so on until all rows have been copied to their matching sheet.

I have figured out how to do it if my column A always had the same values but they could be different for every project.

Comment: Share your sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could be more specific what exactly you want to do.

If I get it right:
You could for e. g.  start your table at row 2 or 3 and type the text that triggers your copy ("SF-1") in cell A1.
You then don't have to hard-code the text in your VBA-code, but can instead use a variable (and assign the text from A1 to it) and use it to compare and decide which rows to copy.